# Embedded Youtube Video not showing in FireFox

Tags: firefox, youtube, fckeditor

I have a page with FCKEditor on it. I have installed the "Embed Video" plugin on it.

When I view this page in any browser (IE, Chrome, Opera, Safari) and embed a youtube video link it previews just fine, but the preview doesn't show up in FireFox!

The HTML generated is as follows:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
    <!-- Lots of FCK Scripts and Styles -->
</head>
<body spellcheck="false">
<object height="225px" width="300px">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;feature">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed height="225" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;feature" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true">
    <noembed>Download movie: &amp;lt;A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;amp;feature"&amp;gt;http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kecWETS1Zck&amp;amp;feature=g-logo&amp;lt;/A&amp;gt;</noembed>
</object><p><br type="_moz"></p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I don't understand why this happening in FF only?

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Why does that matter ? I've tried it on FF 7 & 8

Comment: I have a bit doubt whether that it matter or not. Ok have you tried my answer. First try by closing nodes properly. If it not working then go for other way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution to this.

Firstly, its an inherent FF issue. FF does not show preview of object or embed tags from inside of an iframe.

There is a built in JS class in FCKEditor by the name `FCKEmbedAndObjectProcessor` it has a `RefreshView` function that takes a place holder element (e.g. an img tag and the original embed/object element) and does a replacement so as to show something in the browser canvas.

It automatically saves the embed tag which you can later retrieve by using `fckEditor.UpdateLinkedField()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`<param>` & `<embed>` nodes are not closed properly.

Try this way too:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;feature" height="225px" width="300px">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;feature"/>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"/>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
    <embed height="225" width="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;feature" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true"/>
    <noembed>Download movie: &amp;lt;A HREF="http://www.youtube.com/v/kecWETS1Zck&amp;amp;feature"&amp;gt;http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kecWETS1Zck&amp;amp;feature=g-logo&amp;lt;/A&amp;gt;</noembed>
</object>
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not up to me as the code is being generated correctly at the server-side (with the closing tags) but when its rendered in the browser, i see it like i've pasted it above (without the closing tags) its the browser doing this. But the "exact" same code is working fine on other browsers !